# mac os environment variable set

Tags: macos, gcc, operating-system, g++

Last week, when I am trying to install gcc_select on my macbook, I went through several commands,I did remember I just cd to a certain directory and made some modifications using the root. Everything seems fine, however, I found that when I open the terminal and trying to compile a program by using gcc or g++, it keeps saying that the "command not found".I have to manually to type the :" export PATH=$PATH:/Developer/usr/bin" in order to make the gcc or g++ command run.

My question is , is there anyone please tell me how to permanently change that, so that I don't need to type the same command again and again.

Comment: When you install Xcode, there is an option to install a copy of the toolchain under /usr/bin, so that you don't need to change your PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Developer/usr/bin
```

in the .profile file in your home directory. If it does not exit, create it. Better way would be the one user57368 gave in the comment though.